# 'angular-route.min.js" Error is shown on the HTML page

Tags: angularjs

I have created index.html as below:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="bootProject" >
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>SASS / Home
    </title>
    <script src="../../node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="../../dist/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for font-awesome css -->
    <link href="../../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"                rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>

   <div ng-view></div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    angular-route.min.js
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../javascript/main.js"></script>
    <script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

There is a "home.html" with a navbar that I want to click on "log in" tab and goes in to "log.html" page.

```
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#service">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
          <li><a href="#register">Register</a></li>
          <li><a href="#log">Login</a></li>
          <div><ng-view></div>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

And this is my "main.js":

```
// Module
var weatherApp = angular.module('bootProject',['ngRoute']);
// Route
weatherApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/home',{

            templateUrl:'http://localhost:1337/dist/templates/home.html',
            controller: 'homeController'
        })
        .when('/log',{

            templateUrl:'http://localhost:1337/dist/templates/log.html',
            controller: 'logController' 
        })
        .when('/dashboard',{

            templateUrl:'http://localhost:1337/dist/templates/home.html',
            controller: 'dashboardController'   
        });
});

  //Controllers
weatherApp.controller('logController', [ '$scope', '$location',function($scope,$location){

    $scope.submit= function(){
        var uname = $scope.username;
        console.log(uname);
        var pass = $scope.password;
        if($scope.username =='admin' && $scope.password =='admin'){
        $location.path("/dashboard");
        }
    };
}]);
```

When I open my project in  localhost / dist  it shows me just one line which is "angular-route.min.js", but when I open it in  localhost/src  it shows me the right pages but still I can see that line in log.html page.

Please let me know what my mistake is?

Comment: Do not post your code as image. Please post your code directly as text by editing your question.

Comment: this **is not** an error with `angular.min.js`, it is simply displaying that because, for some reason, you have that *text* in the middle of the script tags in the body.  You have no route that matches the URL you are browsing to, and no `.otherwise`, so the `ng-view` element remains empty.

Comment: Doesn't it consider as a route! I am browsing to log.html page : http://localhost:1337/dist/templates/log.html

Comment: well, even on that route, you still have the ***text*** in the body, outside the `ng-view`. Also, something is wrong really if you have to have `/dist/templates` in your URL.  that's not how the router works.  your route *should be* http://localhost:1337/log.  No `/dist/templates/`, and no `.html`.

Comment: Well I don't have that text in the body it appears by it's own! when I click on that line in elements I see this line " <div ng-view class="ng-scope"> which says it comes from bootstrap ! is this the reason of that line's appearance!?

Comment: you most certainly **do** have that text in the body:  `<script src="../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    angular-route.min.js
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../javascript/main.js"></script>`  The text "angular-route.min.js" is clearly in the body, mixed with other script tags.

Comment: One more question, I am wondering why  /dist/templates  is wrong. All my  minify HTML, JS files and images are there!

Comment: Angular is a Single Page Application (SPA) framework.  This implies that there is a Single Page which is loaded, i.e. only *one* `index.html` ever loaded by the browser.  If you load a **different** `.html` file, then angular is loaded again, and you lose all the variables, scripts, etc. which have already been processed.  The angular router uses ajax to selectively **replace the contents of the `ng-view`**, while still staying on the same `index.html`.  Your user ***should not ever*** access your templates directly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a `.otherwise` in your routing. You should be using `.otherwise` to catch routes that do not match the ones you have specified.

for example, you might use `.otherwise({redirectTo:'/home'});`